# How to set a String variable that receive tag from php script?

Tags: php, android, json

This is my doInBackground

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
  try {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

    Log.d("request!", "starting");
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());                
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
    loginposition = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

    for (int i = 0; i < loginposition.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = loginposition.getJSONObject(i);
      Position = c.getString(TAG_POSITION);
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "JSON error", e);
    success = Integer.valueOf(0);
  }
  return success;
}
```

I declare the Position variable as `String Position` and I don't know why my android json said my success is not 1 or null.. even my tag post.

This is my logcat

```
12-13 15:52:09.830: D/request!(27146): starting
12-13 15:52:13.139: D/Login attempt(27146): {"posts":["user"],"message":"Login Successful!","success":1}
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146): JSON error
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146): org.json.JSONException: Value user at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:157)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at com.pmss.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-13 15:52:13.149: E/(27146):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-13 15:52:13.149: D/Login Failure!(27146): res: Login Successful!
```

Comment: Is loginposition of type JSONArray? Also, what is Position?

Comment: loginposition is JSONArray type yes and `Position` is a string variable that responsible to save the string like `user` and `staff` from my database

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `String[]` in your `posts` and you are trying to cast it to `JSONObject` which is giving you exception.

Try replacing

```
JSONObject c = loginposition.getJSONObject(i);
```

to

```
String jsonText = loginposition.getString(i);
```

Comment: even I change to the `String jsonText = loginposition.getString(i);`  the line of code `Position = jsonText.getString(TAG_POSITION);` have error on it which is `The method getString(String) is undefined for the type String`

Comment: Of course you will get that error as the `getString(String)` is not defined for the `String` class. When you do the above you will get `user` which you receive in `posts` in `jsonText`

Answer (score 0):

If

> "loginposition is JSONArray type yes and Position is a string variable that responsible to save the string like user and staff from my database"

and you have this json:

```
{"posts":["user"],"message":"Login Successful!","success":1}
```

you can do this:

```
//loop through all the entries in loginposition and extract strings for each index
for (int i = 0; i < loginposition.length(); i++) {
  position = loginposition.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

If your json contains more than one user, eg. ["user", "staff"], this loop will go through all of them, so you need to handle this accordingly.

NOTE: remember that by Java convention, you should use variable names with lower case first letter (so 'position' not 'Position').